# Python read file determined by separator \r\n

Tags: python, file, newline

I would like to read file determined by newline separator \r\n only, \r and \n should be treated as part of string, not as end of line.

I was trying to use

```
open('file.txt', 'rU').read().split('\r\n')
```

but after file is opened i do not see any \r character, so probably i have to open file with different flag or different way.

Any ideas how to solve the problem?

EDIT: sorry for not specifying version of python, i'm using version 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open the file with 'rb':

`open('file.txt', 'rb').read().split('\r\n')`

I found it a bit of challenge to create a text file with just CR and just LF, but Notepad++ helped me.

With this content:

`CRLF\r\nCR\rLF\nCRLF\r\n`

using `print open('file.txt', 'rb').read().split('\r\n')`

I got this output:

`['CRLF', 'CR\rLF\nCRLF', '']`

Comment: Well, this isn't binary-type file, so when i'm trying to do it, i have error:
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

Comment: I'm using Python 2.7 - you didn't specify Python 3.

Comment: it works but you have to use `.read().decode().split...` for instance.

Answer (score 3):

[barny answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50525030/6451573) (using binary mode) works perfect in Python 2 but needs adapting in python 3 since opening a file as binary returns its contents as `bytes`, no longer `str`.

Also if the file is big, the fact of reading the whole file at once can be a problem memory-wise.

In Python 3, you can pass the `newline` parameter to `open` so it splits on that instead of the default.

```
with open("temp.txt","r",newline="\r\n") as f:
    for line in f:
       ....
```

`line` contains the text plus `\r\n` at the end (use `line = line.rstrip()` to remove).

If there are `\n` chars in the line (not following `\r`), they are read as a normal character.

Comment: Thanks, this is working as well, but i think the solution that i marked is bit better(less code :) )

Comment: whatever you choose (plus you solved it thanks to my comment about `decode` which isn't even in the answer). Moreover try to open a 30Gb file with the other solution and the full read + split performed at start :)

Comment: anyway, interesting question :)

Answer (score 0):

I think \r\n is being translated to \n when reading a file in text mode.

I'm not 100% sure what you want to achieve, but it looks to me that you want to do:

```
with open("file.txt", "rU") as f:
    return f.readline()
```

This will read one line (including the \n). If you want the lines as list:

```
with open("file.txt", "rU") as f:
    return f.readlines()
```

Or you could just iterate over f.

Comment: I have file like this:
First line \r\n
Second line \n
Third line \r\n
As result of spliting file i should have output like this:
1. String = "First line 
Second line"
2.  String  = "Third line"